# MediatR IPipelineBehavior conversion failed at runtime

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, mediator, mediatr

I have implemented a generic pipeline behavior for my query handlers like the one below:

```cs
public sealed class ErrorHandlerBehaviour<TRequest, TResponse>
    : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, ViewResult<TResponse>>
{
    public async Task<ViewResult<TResponse>> Handle(
        TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken,
        RequestHandlerDelegate<ViewResult<TResponse>> next)
    { 
            return ViewResult.Fail();
    }
}
```

and registered that in the container like:

```cs
services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(
    typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>),
    typeof(ErrorHandlerBehaviour<,>),
    context.ServiceLifetime));
```

I have defined a query and a query handler:

```cs
public class GetStudent : IRequest<ViewResult<Student>>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool ThrowError { get; set; }
}

public class GetStudentHandler
    : IRequestHandler<GetStudent, ViewResult<Student>>
{
    public async Task<ViewResult<Student>> Handle(
        GetStudent request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if( request.ThrowError ) throw new ModelNotFoundException();

        return new Student(request.Id);
    }

    public IViewContext ViewContext { get; }
}
```

but at the runtime when I want to send the query to via mediator instance I get the following error:

> Implementation type 'ErrorHandlerBehaviour`2[GetStudent,ViewResult`1[Student]]' can't be converted to service type 'MediatR.IPipelineBehavior`2[GetStudent,ViewResult`1[Student]]

however when I explicitly define a pipeline behavior for that query handler it works but the generic one does not, is there something I have missed?

Comment: You ran into a limitation of MS.DI. That DI Container can't handle complex generic type mappings such as from `<TRequest, TResponse>` to `<TRequest, ViewResult<TResponse>>`. You should redesign this type or switch to a more feature-rich DI Container.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, I just read about it here: https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Container-Feature-Support